# How to calculate a running total using linq

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

I have a linq query result as shown in the image. In the final query (not shown) I am grouping by Year by LeaveType. However I want to calculate a running total for the leaveCarriedOver per type over years. That is, sick LeaveCarriedOver in 2010 becomes "opening" balance for sick leave in 2011 plus the one for 2011.

[image]

I have done another query on the shown result list that looks like:

```
            var leaveDetails1 = (from l in leaveDetails
            select new
            {
                l.Year,
                l.LeaveType,
                l.LeaveTaken,
                l.LeaveAllocation,
                l.LeaveCarriedOver,
                RunningTotal = leaveDetails.Where(x => x.LeaveType == l.LeaveType).Sum(x => x.LeaveCarriedOver)
            });
```

where leaveDetails is the result from the image.

The resulting RunningTotal is not cumulative as expected. How can I achieve my initial goal. Open to any ideas - my last option will be to do it in javascript in the front-end. Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you could use the Aggregate method from LINQ: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate.aspx. This is equivalent to a fold in functional programming.

Comment: I will give you some hint on how to resolve this, You can do it by getting a `distinct<>` `List<Tuple<int,string>>` of Year(`int`) and LeaveType(i assume it's `string`). To get this, a simple `Distinct<>` followed by a `Select<>` should give you that. Then that list is the totals you can actually accumulate. Now using that new list you need to do a `Select<>` and return a new object so lets say `Tuple<int,string,int>` where the first 2 param are the same as the other list but the last int you need the details list with a`Where<>` to filter for year/leavetype then return the `Sum<>` of that.

Comment: @Franck your comment is making sense to me but I just am not getting right with my linq query. Can you please post an answer with the implementation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The simple implementation is to get the list of possible totals first then get the sum from the details for each of these categories.

getting the distinct list of `Year` and `LeaveType` is a group by and select first of each group. we return a `List<Tuple<int, string>>` where `Int` is the year and `string` is the LeaveType

```
 var distinctList = leaveDetails1.GroupBy(data => new Tuple<int, string>(data.Year, data.LeaveType)).Select(data => data.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

then we want total for each of these elements so you want a select of that list to return the id (`Year` and `LeaveType`) plus the total so an extra value to the `Tuple<int, string, int>`.

```
var totals = distinctList.Select(data => new Tuple<int, string, int>(data.Year, data.LeaveType, leaveDetails1.Where(detail => detail.Year == data.Year && detail.LeaveType == data.LeaveType).Sum(detail => detail.LeaveCarriedOver))).ToList();
```

reading the line above you can see it take the distinct totals we want to list, create a new object, store the `Year` and `LeaveType` for reference then set the last `Int` with the `Sum<>` of the filtered details for that `Year` and `LeaveType`.

Answer (score 0):

If I completely understand what you are trying to do then I don't think I would rely on the built in LINQ operators exclusively.  I think (emphasis on think) that any combination of the built in LINQ operators is going to solve this problem in O(n^2) run-time.

If I were going to implement this in LINQ then I would create an extension method for IEnumerable that is similar to the `Scan` function in reactive extensions (or find a library out there that has already implemented it):

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TAccumulate> Scan<TSource, TAccumulate>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
        TAccumulate seed, 
        Func<TAccumulate, TSource, TAccumulate> accumulator)
    {
        // Validation omitted for clarity.
        foreach(TSource value in source)
        {
            seed = accumulator.Invoke(seed, value);
            yield return seed;
        }
    }
}
```

Then this should do it around O(n log n) (because of the order by operations):

```
leaveDetails
.OrderBy(x => x.LeaveType)
.ThenBy(x => x.Year)
.Scan(new {
        Year = 0,
        LeaveType = "Seed",
        LeaveTaken = 0,
        LeaveAllocation = 0.0,
        LeaveCarriedOver = 0.0,
        RunningTotal = 0.0
    }, 
    (acc, x) => new {
        x.Year,
        x.LeaveType,
        x.LeaveTaken,
        x.LeaveAllocation,
        x.LeaveCarriedOver,
        RunningTotal = x.LeaveCarriedOver + (acc.LeaveType != x.LeaveType ? 0 : acc.RunningTotal)
    });
```

You don't say, but I assume the data is coming from a database; if that is the case then you could get `leaveDetails` back already sorted and skip the sorting here.  That would get you down to O(n).

If you don't want to create an extension method (or go find one) then this will achieve the same thing (just in an uglier way).

```
var temp = new 
    { 
        Year = 0, 
        LeaveType = "Who Cares", 
        LeaveTaken = 3, 
        LeaveAllocation = 0.0, 
        LeaveCarriedOver = 0.0, 
        RunningTotal = 0.0 
    };
var runningTotals = (new[] { temp }).ToList();
runningTotals.RemoveAt(0);

foreach(var l in leaveDetails.OrderBy(x => x.LeaveType).ThenBy(x => x.Year))
{
    var s = runningTotals.LastOrDefault();
    runningTotals.Add(new 
        {
            l.Year,
            l.LeaveType,
            l.LeaveTaken,
            l.LeaveAllocation,
            l.LeaveCarriedOver,
            RunningTotal = l.LeaveCarriedOver + (s == null || s.LeaveType != l.LeaveType ? 0 : s.RunningTotal)
        });
}
```

This should also be O(n log n) or O(n) if you can pre-sort `leaveDetails`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question you want something like

```
decimal RunningTotal = 0;

var results = leaveDetails
    .GroupBy(r=>r.LeaveType)
    .Select(r=> new 
    {  
        Dummy = RunningTotal = 0 ,
        results = r.OrderBy(o=>o.Year)
        .Select(l => new 
            {
                l.Year,
                l.LeaveType ,
                l.LeaveAllocation,
                l.LeaveCarriedOver,  
                RunningTotal = (RunningTotal = RunningTotal + l.LeaveCarriedOver )  
            })
    })
    .SelectMany(a=>a.results).ToList();
```

This is basically using the `Select<TSource, TResult>` overload to calculate the running balance, but first grouped by LeaveType so we can reset the RunningTotal for every LeaveType, and then ungrouped at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Window Function Sum here. Which is not supported by EF Core and earlier versions of EF. So, just write SQL and run it via Dapper

```
SELECT 
   l.Year,
   l.LeaveType,
   l.LeaveTaken,
   l.LeaveAllocation,
   l.LeaveCarriedOver,
   SUM(l.LeaveCarriedOver) OVER (PARTITION BY l.Year, l.LeaveType) AS RunningTotal     
FROM leaveDetails l
```

Or, if you are using EF Core, use package [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore)

```
var leaveDetails1 = from l in leaveDetails
   select new
   {
       l.Year,
       l.LeaveType,
       l.LeaveTaken,
       l.LeaveAllocation,
       l.LeaveCarriedOver,
       RunningTotal = Sql.Ext.Sum(l.LeaveCarriedOver).Over().PartitionBy(l.Year, l.LeaveType).ToValue()
   };

// switch to alternative LINQ translator
leaveDetails1 = leaveDetails1.ToLinqToDB();
```